# Conservation of momentum in 3D space to find mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I'm hoping to get some clarification in the use of conservation of momentum in a 3D system. Say you have a rocket with some velocity $v_1$ and mass $m_1$. At time $t$, the rocket breaks into two separate pieces such that each piece has masses $m_2$ and $m_3$ (not necessarily equal) and at times $t+dt$ ($dt$ very small), the velocities of the objects are $v_2$ and $v_3$. Assume that $m_1, v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$ are known. I want to find $m_2$ and $m_3$.

Not taking into account fuel, energy, debris, etc., how would the conservation of momentum be used? I know-
\begin{gather*}
p_i = p_f= p_2 + p_3
\\
m_1v_1 = m_2v_2 + m_3v_3 
\end{gather*}
and using the available information, the problem could be solved easily:
\begin{gather*}
m_1v_1 = m_2v_2 + (m_1 - m_2)v_3
\\
m_1(v_1 - v_3) = m_2(v_2 - v_3)
\\
\frac{m_3}{m_1} = \frac{v_1 - v_3}{v_2 - v_3}
\\
m_3 = m_1 - m_2
\end{gather*}
But for my 3d problem, I'm not getting the expected solutions. Would you need to use the relative velocities or norm of each velocity? Or is there a different kinematic equation that could be applied here?

Comment: In the next to last equation, you lost an $m_1$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. I was using mass fractions in my notes so that m1 = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same approach should suffice. What we would do as more-experienced physicists would be to translate into the center-of-mass frame which moves with velocity $\mathbf v_1,$ so that we are only concerned with velocities $\mathbf u_{2,3} = \mathbf v_{2,3} - \mathbf v_1$ for which we must know that (since the original momentum in this frame is zero), $$m_2 \mathbf u_2 + m_3 \mathbf u_3 = 0.$$

Knowing the three velocities $\mathbf v_{1,2,3}$ therefore allows us to calculate precisely the ratio $r = m_2/m_3 = \|\mathbf u_3\|/\|\mathbf u_2\|$ for example, and then it is clear that $$\begin{align}
m_2 &= \frac{r}{1 + r}~m_1\\
m_3 &= \frac{1}{1 + r}~m_1
\end{align}
$$ is the unique solution guaranteeing that $m_2/m_3 = r$ but also $m_2 + m_3 = m_1.$

The use of the norm above is kind of just one way to do it; the equation says that the two vectors have the same direction so you can certainly use the norm but you can also e.g. use the negative ratio of the $x$-components of the vector to find the same scale-factor. The point is that if you discover that the two velocities are not opposite-directional in this special frame of reference, then in that frame of reference you are describing a violation of conservation of momentum $m_2\mathbf u_2 + m_3 \mathbf u_3 \ne 0$ which must also exist when we add $m_1 \mathbf v_1$ to both sides of the inequality and then have $m_2 \mathbf v_2 + m_3 \mathbf v_3 \ne m_1 \mathbf v_1.$

Part of the reason that any more-experienced physicist knows this is that the center-of-mass calculations are indispensible for not losing your head when the math all becomes relativistic; another reason is that the same fundamental trick allows you to solve in classical mechanics any two-body central-force problem by reducing it to a one-body problem, which is why you have to go to the [three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) to see interesting complexities: the fact that the two vectors have opposite direction means that you can encode the entire system in one vector and the fact that the mass ratio determines the magnitude of one vector from the other means that you do not even need to keep an extra scalar dynamic variable around.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Would the conservation of momentum only hold when using the velocities immediately before/after the separation? Or only exactly at the point of separation (so that pieces would be propagated to point of separation)?<br/>  If so, say the separation occurs during some short time interval where no data is available. Assuming this is a closed system where mass and velocities are known, could the con. of momentum be used to find where exactly in time the separation occurred (via propagating)?